# How to create XACML PEP Request using WSO2 Balana?

Tags: wso2, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I would like to use WSO2 Balana XACML. I found it's an open source solution,can I have some details regarding PEP and PDP and the classes responsible to create XACML request ?

Answer (score 4):

Balana is an Open source XACML (3.0/2.0/1.1/1.0) library. It is basically PDP. Once XACML request can be fed in to this library, XACML result can be retrieved based on the defined policies. You can find more details on Balana from [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/category/balana/) web site. PEP is an separate component from the PDP and it basically within the application level. Balana has and util library to create XACML request and even policies. where you can find it from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-utils/).  Also Balana library is used by WSO2 Identity Server (open source )which can be actually used as PDP/PAP/PIP server. Also this server contains a simple UI to create XACML requests and policies (that uses Balana utility library). Please find more details from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/)

Comment: Hi Thank you very much,could i have the sample exmples of how to create XACML Request?

Comment: some java code can be found here  https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pep/simple-agent/src/main/java/org/xacmlinfo/xacml/pep/agent/util/PEPUtils.java

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.I got the solution and i did it.shall we have to pay anything when it goes to production environment?

Comment: Great..!!!  You do not want to pay any thing...  Balana is an open source library based on Apache 2 licence.  You can use it free, and if you want you can change the code... Please check the README and NOTICE https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/README.txt

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support.As i told you i downloaded Balana Source and started working on it.Now i would like to implement PIP extension for hierarchical resources.could you please give best suggestion?

Comment: Here you can find a resource finder extension http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/01/09/authorization-for-hierarchical-resources-with-xacml-multiple-decision-profile/